# Can't read double in Java

Tags: java

I'm using the following code:

```
            String val = scanner.nextLine();
            Scanner line = new Scanner(val);
            System.out.println(val);
            System.out.println(line.nextDouble());
```

Of which the output is:

```
9.612771780095113E-25 10.0 0.0 0.7660444431190742 1.2679145539688897E-5 0.0 1.0E11
null
```

Where null is the exception message that I catch (`e.getMessage`). I don't understand how this can be? Why does it not recognize double values in this string?

Comment: What is the exception type you catch?

Comment: Wild guess : maybe your system doesn't recognize dot for decimal, rather it recognizes comma? So instead try String val = "9,612771780095113E-25";

Comment: Post all your code that is relevant. You didn't post the code that prints the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to javadoc, [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) by default use localized symbols; read the section *Localized numbers*. If you don't know your locale, call Locale.getDefault() and inspect your localized symbols, then use them for you doubles.

Comment: Yes indeed, `line.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);` makes it work. Thanks.